# "Cannot find class symbol" error in Maven for running Geo Tools

Tags: java, maven, svn, geotools

I am new to using Geo Tools and Maven. I'm following the tutorial and came across a specific error. The code I'm trying to run is available [here](http://svn.osgeo.org/geotools/tags/post-migration/docs/src/main/java/org/geotools/grid/GridExamples.java).

My pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
  <artifactId>tutorial</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>10.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>tutorial</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>10.1</geotools.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
     <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
     <plugins>
          <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
               </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
</build>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
           <artifactId>gt-grid</artifactId>
           <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
           <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
           <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>gov.nist.math</groupId>
        <artifactId>jama</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
   <repositories>
       <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository> <!--Add the snapshot repository here-->
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>opengeo</id>
        <name>OpenGeo Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.opengeo.org</url>
    </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

And as I mentioned I am trying to run the same code provided in the above link.

The error I receive is:

```
line 122: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class IntersectionBuilder
  location: class org.geotools.grid.GridExamples
```

Is there a class missing? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing the second class http://svn.osgeo.org/geotools/tags/post-migration/docs/src/main/java/org/geotools/grid/IntersectionBuilder.java

Comment: @Pavel, Thanks, you're right. However, now there is no error in the code, but when I run the code there is no result. The aim is to create vector grids mentioned in this link:
http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/grid.html

I use the same code, but I don't see any output. Isn't there any code missing in the functions for view/storing the create grids? Any help would be great!

Comment: I am not familiar with *geotools*... I am also not sure what *example code* you are trying to run. Maybe post a bit more about the code (you can delete your POM from the question).

Comment: @Pavel, thank you for you respone. The code I'm trying to run is here http://svn.osgeo.org/geotools/tags/post-migration/docs/src/main/java/org/geotools/grid/GridExamples.java

Comment: looking at the example it is only showing how to construct grids. It does not return or print anything.

Comment: @Pavel, exactly. Do you have any examples/links that show how the produced grids can be stored in shapefile? I am totally new to Maven and Geotools. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to using geotools with maven myself and ran into similar issues recently. If I am not mistaken, gt-grid is an unsupported module. So you might need to download the source and build it in order to use it. I cannot seem to find the GridExamples class at http://svn.osgeo.org/geotools/tags/post-migration/modules/unsupported/grid/src/main/java/org/geotools/grid/

Comment: what I'm interested to build is the Hexagon grid, which you can fine the classes at: http://svn.osgeo.org/geotools/tags/post-migration/modules/unsupported/grid/src/main/java/org/geotools/grid/hexagon/
But again, the code misses parts where you view/store the created grid. Is this true? Do you know what could be the solution?